# Open a new tab on button click after adding a record in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have a AddNewProject page where user enter some information in a formview and click a LinkButton to insert the record. Also, in the button click event I have response.redirect to go a details page. Everything works fine but the details page opens in the same tab. I want it to open in a new tab. 
I have tried

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "OpenWindow", "window.open('pageUrl','_blank');", True)
```

and

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open ('" + pageUrl + "', '_blank');</script>") but gets an error.
```

So in my aspx page I have:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddLease" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"  CommandName="Insert" Text="Create" Font-Bold="True"  ValidationGroup="AddLease" onclick="lbAddLease_Click" />
```

My Button click event:

```
Protected Sub lbAddLease_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
'has code to insert record
Dim varNewId As String
varNewId = command.Parameters("@Result").Value.ToString()
Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx?tab=0&msg=saved&update=true&projectid=" + varNewId + "&type=lease")
End Sub
```

My question is how to open the details page in a new tab.
Thanks in advance.